# Set the selected row css properties for a Google Visualization Table Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I am struggling to understand how the CSS properties are overridden when using the cssClassNames property in Google Visualization API, I think its pretty clear from the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options), but somehow I cant make it work.

My ultimate goal here is to set a custom background-color for selected rows. So far my efforts have been to use the  cssClassNames to specify a class for the selected row and set it in my CSS for the document. I can see that the font  properties work correctly (font-style, text-decoration, etc), but when trying to use the background-color property it just doesnt work!

My js:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
      ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
      ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
      ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
    ]);
    var cssClassNames = {
       'selectedTableRow': 'selectedTableRow',
       'oddTableRow': 'selectedTableRow'};
            var options = {'showRowNumber': true, 'allowHtml': true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames};
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, options);
  }
```

And the CSS:

```
.selectedTableRow {
  font-style: italic;
  color: purple;
  font-size:15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 3px solid gold;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6e2xw5cd/4/

I also tried the other available classes, but these seem to be able to implement the CSS background properties just fine. On the following JSFiddle you can notice the behaviour when setting oddTableRows the same as selectedTableRows: https://jsfiddle.net/3kecdaz0/

So I am wondering if its possible at all to set background properties for selected rows in the Google Visualization Chart Table element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `background-color: beige !important;` to override background color.

```
.selectedTableRow {
    font-style: italic;
    color: purple;
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 3px solid gold;
    background-color: beige !important;
  }
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e2xw5cd/5/)**

Or try to include your custom css file after `table.css`.

Comment: Thanks! Issue is solved! Although seems like google api is missing something if we have to go to the extent of overriding their styling.

Answer (score 2):

In order to override the proeperty value you have to add !important;

Change `background-color: beige`; to

```
background-color: beige !important;
```

Comment: Thanks Tanveer, Ketan answered literally 4 minutes before you